# How to read the User Reputation Leagues table?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I stumbled upon a page called "[User Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2013-03-01/1636522?sort=reputationchange#1636522)" which displays a list of users. I can't figure out what purpose it serves and how to read it, especially the first two columns. I have two questions :

- How "month rank" is calculated?
- What is "change" and how is it calculated?

[image: User Reputation Leagues screenshot]

---

### Edit

Two more questions after reading comments :

- Is there any chart to see changes over the months?
- Where is the link to access the page?

---

### Edit

Last one : How this percentage ("top 2% this month") is calculated?

[image]

Comment: "change" is the change in rank since the last month.

Comment: @Mysticial You mean my prevent rank was #(416 + 17329)?

Comment: month rank is your rank this month, by month reputation... the leagues are ordered by this.

Comment: yes​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Is there any chart to see changes over the months?

Comment: It's accessible in user profile page of users with more than 200 rep (meaning they are part of the league) e.g. your profile: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6tBSU.png

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: there are about 29,640 total users in the league. This means 1% is 296 so anyone ranked in the first 296 places will be "top 1% this month", being ranked in the first 592 places means "top 2%" etc.. and you're ranked #416 :)

Comment: Thanks, now I see the missing part : "You are part of the top 2% this month"... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see, from left-to-right:

1. User info (avatar, name + link, badge count, how long ago they joined)
2. The ranking in this league. For the monthly league, ranked by how much reputation you gained in the current calendar month, but there is also a weekly league (current week starting on sundays), and quarterly, yearly and overall leagues. It's the place the user ended up at when the table was sorted on the last column.
3. Change from the *previous* ranking for this league. A positive number means the user rose in rank, negative means you dropped.
4. The *total* amount of reputation the user had at the time the rankings were calculated. (*This can be lower than the last column*; you can have lost reputation to bounties and such).
5. The reputation change this week / month / quarter / year, or for the total rep league, the total reputation, at the time the league table was generated.

So, for your specific example: you are ranked 416th, you gained 17329 places compared to the previous month, were you were ranked 416 + 17329 = 17745th.

You can visit previous rankings with the links at the top, but there is no graph charting rank placings; these tend to jump around a lot for most people. For Jon Skeet, it'd be a rather monotonous almost-straight line.

Most sites include a 'top [percentage] this [league]' on the user summary page by the recent reputation changes table. When visiting the "Users" tab, there is a link at the bottom of the pages to the leagues. You'll also find a tab on https://stackexchange.com/ ("Top Users").