# Column headers for the reputation changes league

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

The following questions indicate that the "Change" column in the reputation league is confusing, and often mistakenly thought to indicate a change in reputation, while in actuality, it is a change in rank.

[Explanation of columns in reputation league](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130117/explanation-of-columns-in-reputation-league/241908)

[What does "Change" represent in the User Leagues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63476/what-does-change-represent-in-the-user-leagues)

[sudden surge of thousands in reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202198/sudden-surge-of-thousands-in-reputation)

[How to read the User Reputation Leagues table?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170003/how-to-read-the-user-reputation-leagues-table)

[What is +XXXX [any number] change in stackexchange user of the week?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225605/what-is-xxxx-any-number-change-in-stackexchange-user-of-the-week)

Adding column headers to the league would solve this problem. The column in question would be "Rank change".